# How to set dropdown with values depending on another dropdown if both are set to required

Tags: validation, jsf, selectonemenu, ajax-update

Can anyone tell me how to automatically set `<h:selectOneMenu>` (or any other component) with values depending on another `<h:selectOneMenu>` if there empty elements with 'required' set to 'true' on the form? If to set `<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="anotherElement" immediate="true" />` then nothing is changed because changed value isn't set. But without `immediate="true"` I always have message that this or that element cannot be empty. Here's code example that doesn't work.

```
<h:outputLabel value="* #{msg.someField}: "/>
<h:panelGrid cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="someSelect"
            value="#{MyBean.someObj.someId}"
            required="true" label="#{msg.someField}"
            >
        <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="anotherSelect" limitToList="true" immediate="true"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue=""/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.someList}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <rich:message for="someSelect" styleClass="redOne"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:outputLabel value="* #{msg.anotherField}: "/>
<h:panelGrid cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="anotherSelect"
            value="#{MyBean.someObj.anotherId}"
            required="true" label="#{msg.anotherField}"
            >
        <f:selectItem itemValue=""/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.anotherList}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <rich:message for="anotherSelect" styleClass="redOne"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:outputLabel value="* #{msg.name}: "/>
<h:panelGrid cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <h:inputText id="myName" value="#{MyBean.someObj.myName}" 
            required="true" label="#{msg.name}"/>
    <rich:message for="myName" styleClass="redOne"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

So, here (I repeat), if I try to change 'someSelect' then 'anotherSelect' should update its values but it doesn't because either when it tries to get value of 'someSelect' it gets null (if `immediate` set to `true`) or form validation fails on empty elements. How can I skip validation but get this changed value from 'someSelect'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `ajaxSingle="true"` to the someSelect a4j:support element?  Remove the `immediate="true"`

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works in JSF 2.0

```
<h:outputLabel
    value="* Country: "/>
<h:selectOneMenu
    id="someSelect"
    value="#{testController.countryName}"
    required="true">
    <f:selectItem
        itemLabel="Select Country"
        itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{testController.countryNamesSelectItems}"/>
    <!-- This will only update "someSelect" and repaint "anotherSelect" -->
    <f:ajax
        execute="@this"
        render="anotherSelect"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputLabel
    value="* State: "/>
<h:selectOneMenu
    id="anotherSelect"
    value="#{testController.stateName}"
    required="true">
    <f:selectItem
        itemLabel="Select State"
        itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{testController.stateNamesSelectItems}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The f:ajax call will submit an ajax request to the server onchange of "someSelect". The model update for only the "someSelect" component will happen (because of execute="@this"). In the render response phase, only "anotherSelect" will be re-rendered (thus invoking testController.stateNamesSelectItems with the updated country name).

As a result of all this, the states of the selected country will get updated as an when country is changed...the ajax way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but i use jsf 1.2. :)